# CentOS Dual-screen doesn't work

Tags: multiple-monitors, centos, nvidia-graphics-card

I am running a CentOS 5.3 x86_64 (fully updated as of today).  It has a video card I cannot identify -- I run *lspci* and it identifies itself as:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Unknown device 0615 (rev a2)
```

The previous admin left me with the linux driver NVIDIA-x86_64-185.18.31-pkg2.run and having installed that it seems to work properly in single monitor mode.

I have two identical monitors.  Both are connected through DVI connectors on the back of the video card.

However when I try to enable dual-monitor mode through the *Display* menu applet, it doesn't work.  The computer starts the NVidia driver and then kicks back to the command prompt.

The tail end of the Xorg.log file is:

```
Backtrace:
0: X(xf86SigHandler+0x71) [0x4865b1]
1: /lib64/libc.so.6 [0x303de30280]
2: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/librac.so [0x2aedd36f803a]

Fatal server error:
Caught signal 4.  Server aborting

(II) Screen 0 shares mem & io resources
(II) Screen 1 shares mem & io resources
```

I have also done some fooling with the xorg.conf file directly such as duplicating the monitor definition between screens, but it always dies the same way.

Does anyone know how I might identify this card's chip properly to ensure I have the correct driver, and is there a good guide on the web anywhere for manually configuring two monitors off of one video card?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hah.  I knew that as soon as I asked, I'd figure it out.

What I did:

- in the Display applet, select Dual Head, the "second" video card, and Spanning Dekstops.
- select a random LCD display that is sized appropriately.
- exit X.
- in /etc/xorg.conf: remove the second Monitor definition and duplicate the first Monitor definition.  Rename the second Monitor definition to be *Identifier "Monitor1"*.
- in /etc/xorg.conf: Confirm the *Device* section for *Videocard1* is correct -- the Display applet left it using the *vesa* instead of the *nvidia* driver.
- in /etc/xorg.conf: I also deleted the *resolution* line, since it was *640x480*.

Now it works.

I'd still be interested in how to identify the chip on the card, though.

**Update, much later**: [this site](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=606) lists the PCI device numbers for nVidia chips.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message but this solution did not work for me. I fixed mine using the nvidia-settings GUI. In this GUI the second monitor was disabled, once I enabled it I got it to work. Also be sure to save the changes to the config file with the button provided.