# Setting up a second monitor in CentOS

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, display, centos

I have CentOS installed on my laptop. I hooked up my TV via VGA and it works, just not as I'd like it to. The left side (on the TV) is cut off, like the image is justified too far left. I want it to be centered, but I also want to use a different resolution. I use a netbook, and thus my laptop screen is tiny, meaning some things can't fit in the same window without scrolling. I want my TV to fix that for me.

Answer (score -1):

Would the following link be what you are looking for? [CentOS Dual-screen doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/21119/centos-dual-screen-doesnt-work) If you need anymore help, comment.

-Hope this helps

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were having issues. Does you TV have HDMI, VGA, or DVI inputs?

Comment: yes. Ive connected to the TV to the laptop via VGA.

Comment: @Rob I was asking about all the inputs, because different inputs support different resolutions. Have you tried changing the resolution? If so, what were the issues/outcome? It sounds like you just have the resolution set wrong. The following link will help you set the resolution in cent os if you don't know how. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-distributions-5/%5Bcentos%5D-screen-resolution-setting-549103/

Comment: xrandr help at all ? Ended literally days of messing around with xorg.conf for me, in just a few minutes. dont use a xorg.conf file at all now.